# Create drop down menu in seam with s:selectItems

Tags: java, jsf, seam, facelets

I have just started to learn seam framework. I decided to code two drop down menus. One listing categories and other listing subcategory. The idea is that user will first select a category and depending on that a subcategory will be populated.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{manager.category}" required="true">
          <a:support event="onfocus" ajaxSingle="true" action="#{manager.dothis()}"/>
          <s:selectItems value="#{manager.categories}" var="cat" label="#{cat.categoryDescription}" noSelectionLabel="Select a Category"/>
          <s:convertEntity />
```

Above, I am trying to call dothis() method on event focus but its not working.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Is your #{manager.categories} already populated?
2. What does #{manager.dothis()} do?

You probably don't want to do anything `onfocus()` ...unless maybe you're lazy loading the initial values (which I don't think you are). You should also be reRendering something in the `<a:support>` tag otherwise your action won't affect anything on your page.

Here's my approach to these (assumes #{manager.categories} is populated):

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="category" value="#{manager.category}" required="true">
          <a:support event="onchange" ajaxSingle="true" action="#{manager.populateSubCategories()}" reRender="subcategory"/>
          <s:selectItems value="#{manager.categories}" var="cat" label="#{cat.categoryDescription}" noSelectionLabel="Select a Category"/>
          <s:convertEntity />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:selectOneMenu id="subcategory" value="#{manager.subcategory}" required="true">
          <s:selectItems value="#{manager.subcategories}" var="subcat" label="#{subcat.categoryDescription}" noSelectionLabel="Select a Sub-Category"/>
          <s:convertEntity />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my bean:

```
@Stateful
@Name("requestManager")
public class RequestManagerBean implements RequestManager
{
    @Logger private Log log;

    @In StatusMessages statusMessages;

    private Category category;

    private Subcategory subcategory;

    @Out(required=false)
    private List categories;

    private List subcategories;

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;
    public void createRequest()
    {
        // implement your business logic here
        log.info("manager.createRequest() action called with: #{manager.value}");
        statusMessages.add("createRequest #{manager.value}");
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }


    public Subcategory getSubcategory() {
        return subcategory;
    }

    public void setSubcategory(Subcategory subcategory) {
        this.subcategory = subcategory;
    }

    public List getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(List categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public List getSubcategories() {
        //System.out.println("returning " + subcategories.size() + "subcategories..");
        return subcategories;
    }

    public void setSubcategories(List subcategories) {
        this.subcategories = subcategories;
    }

    @Destroy
    @Remove
    public void destroy() {}

    @Factory("categories")
    public void loadCat() {
        System.out.println("loadCat called..........");
        categories = entityManager.createQuery("select c from Category c order by c.categoryDescription").getResultList();
    }

    public void callme() {

        System.out.println("callme............");
        subcategories = category.getSubcategoryList();
        System.out.println(subcategories.size());
    }
}
```

and form

`<rich:panel>
        <f:facet name="header">Create Request</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="Category: "/>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="categoryField" value="#{requestManager.category}">
            <s:selectItems var="cat" value="#{categories}" label="#{cat.categoryDescription}" noSelectionLabel="Select a Category"/>
            <s:convertEntity />
            <a:support  event="onchange" ajaxSingle="true" action="#{requestManager.callme}" reRender="subcategoryField" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <br />
        <br />
        <h:outputText value="Subcategory: "/>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="subcategoryField" value="#{requestManager.subcategory}" required="true">
                  <s:selectItems value="#{requestManager.subcategories}" var="subcat" label="#{subcat.subcategoryDescription}" noSelectionLabel="Select a Sub-Category"/>
                <s:convertEntity />
        </h:selectOneMenu>

        <div style="clear:both"/>

    </rich:panel>

    <div class="actionButtons">
        <h:commandButton id="createRequest" value="Submit"
                action="#{requestManager.createRequest}"/>
    </div>

</h:form>`

/pre>

Comment: @alkesh Use @Factory It is evaluated once, and just once. Advice: Do not use post an answer when you want to post a comment. See link add comment

Comment: What is the difference between @Factory and @Create. And, I tried code above for some reason manager.populateCategories() is not being called. Also, I do I debug it. I am using log.debug() but where are those logs stored?

Thanks guys, I appreciate you taking time helping me out.

Comment: alright, so i figured out the diff between Factory and Create.
Now, only the problem is that action is not working onchange.

Comment: i get the following error:
20:03:03,999 INFO  [lifecycle] WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=managerForm:j_id13[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(value is not valid), detail=(value is not valid)]

What am I doing wrong? BTW, both selectOneMenus are enclosed in rich:panel.

Comment: I think, i have it right now. But why is my method "callme" not being called on change event.

Comment: You should not post questions/updates as **answers**. They will get lost into noise. This isn't a forum. Use the `edit` link below your question to add updates. Use the `add comment` link to add comments. Finally delete this "answer".

Comment: @BalusC, I am sorry about that. I cleared my history on my pc, so it didn't recognize me. So, I couldn't modify my earlier post. Thanks for clearing it out though.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. I'd suggest to register yourself then :)